# How do you name an int with an expression so that a code will make a given number of ints and name them (c++)?

Tags: c++, variables

I would like to create any number of ints with names A, B, C ... etc. and set them equal to 0. These variables will be numbers of species, which i will then use for other functions. I do not want to make all of the variables every time i want to have a different number of species, I just want to enter a number.

```
//EX: This pseudocode makes int A = 0,B = 0, C = 0

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numSpecies = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < numSpecies; i++)
    {
        int ('i' + 17) = 0; // '0' + 17 = 'A', and int A = 0;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all

Comment: An array or vector would be more suited to this.

Comment: You may be thinking of more dynamic languages like Python where you can add/remove global variables at run time. C++ cannot do this. Place the values in an `vector` or, if you want to refer to them with strings, a `map`.

Comment: There is no requirement in C or C++ that `'0' + 17 == 'A'`. It's true for the ASCII encoding, which is quite common, but there are others.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of more dynamic languages like Python where you can add/remove global variables at run time. C++ cannot do this. Place the values in an `vector` or, if you want to refer to them with strings, a `map`. Here is one possible solution using a `map`:

```
// INFO: This real code solves the issue ;)

#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numSpecies = 3;
    map<string, int> species;
    string letters[] = ["A", "B", "C"];

    for(int i = 0; i < numSpecies; i++)
    {
        species[letters[i]] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```